# Why the null checking of path.length in deepGet function is placed in end of it?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

deepGet function in underscore.js implements like this:

```
var deepGet = function(obj, path) {
    var length = path.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (obj == null) return void 0;
      obj = obj[path[i]];
    }
    return length ? obj : void 0;
  };
```

Why it's not implement like this:

```
var deepGet = function(obj, path) {
    var length = path.length;
    if (!length)
      return void 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (obj == null) return void 0;
      obj = obj[path[i]];
    }
    return obj;
  };
```

If 'length' is null or zero, in first one run 2 checking(for,?:) but in second one only 1 checking(if(!length))

I'm learning javascript and I want to know why?

Comment: There's no significant difference. It's just a matter of style.